# Was bedeuten die Wörter "über" und "auf" in der Mathematik?

Tags: meaning, etymology, history, mathematics

Was bedeuten die Wörter "über" und "auf" in der Mathematik?

Beispiele:

- Vektorraum *über* einem Körper
- Funktion/Relation *auf* einer Menge
- Zeichenkette *über* einem Alphabet

Warum benutzt man diese Wörter "auf" und "über" in diesem Kontext, und wie kann man entscheiden, wann man diese Begriffe benutzen darf? Ich bin mir bspw. manchmal nicht sicher, ob es nun "Automorphismus *von* einem Objekt X" oder "Automorphismus *auf* einem Objekt X" heißt, oder ob man von einer "Struktur *über* einer Signatur" oder "Struktur *zu* einer gegebenen Signatur" sprechen sollte.

Wie hat es sich historisch entwickelt, dass man diese Begriffe "über" und "auf" in der Mathematik verwendet, und inwiefern hat diese Verwendung von "über" und "auf" mit der eigentlichen Bedeutung von diesen beiden Wörtern zu tun? Im Duden finde ich keine passende Bedeutung für diese Wörter im math. Kontext in der Bedeutungsübersicht.

Comment: Ich vermute man sollte es so verstehen Vektorraum definiert über einem Körper bzw. Funktion definiert auf einer Menge. Vor allem bei Funktionen spielt der Definitionsbereich eine Rolle.

Comment: Das ist jetzt nur spekulativ und mein Sprachgefühl: Man definiert eine neue Struktur **über / aufbauend auf** einer bekannten Struktur.

Comment: Might be good to ask this over on the English math site too as the English is very similar, if not identical. (Probably because these terms originated from German textbooks.) E.g. *Vector spaces over feilds*, *Algebras over fields*, *Relations on sets* [but I've seen *'functions over sets'* too] http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6rper_(Algebra)  u. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebra   - Not surprisingly, the German explainer is much better, IMO ... math in German makes more sense to me than it does in English (and I'm a native English speaker LOL)

Comment: Bei Automorphismus kannst Du auch schreiben _Automorphismus eines Objektes X_.

Answer (score 4):

Zur Historie kann ich nichts sagen. Die Vorstellung, die der Verwendung
von "über" bzw. "auf" in mathematischen Definitionen zugrundeliegt,
ist aber ziemlich offensichtlich:

Wenn wir ein Haus bauen, dann tun wir das von unten nach oben.
Dieses Bild finden wir in der Sprache an verschiedenen Stellen
wieder. Wir sagen z. B., daß etwas die *Grundlage* für etwas anderes ist
(also wörtlich genommen, daß es *auf dem Grund (= Boden) liegt*),
oder daß etwas *auf etwas anderem aufbaut*. Genau diese Vorstellung
steckt nun  auch in den angegebenen Beispielen: Wir müssen einen
Körper definieren, bevor wir einen Vektorraum definieren können;
wir brauchen eine Menge, bevor wir Funktionen definieren können;
wir brauchen einen Zeichenvorrat, bevor wir Zeichenketten definieren können.
Der Körper liegt also dem Vektorraum zugrunde, bzw. der
Vektorraum ist auf dem Körper aufgebaut.

Bleibt noch die Unterscheidung zwischen "über" und "auf".
Das ist nun reine Konvention.
Üblicherweise verwendet man "auf" für Funktionen und Relationen
auf einer Menge
und "über" für algebraische Strukturen, die auf anderen Strukturen aufbauen.
Diese Trennung ist aber nicht scharf, beispielsweise würde ich eher
von einem "Funktionenraum *über* einer Menge" sprechen,
aber die Elemente dieses Funktionenraums sind dann
"Funktionen *auf* der Menge".
Häufig ist das Geschmackssache.
Wenn Du Dir nicht sicher bist, frag die Suchmaschine Deines
Vertrauens, welche Variante die häufigere ist,
oder umgehe das Problem, indem Du von einem "*K*-Vektorraum"
statt einem "Vektorraum auf/über *K*" sprichst.

Answer (score 2):

(Präambel für Nicht-Mathematiker: Ein *Paar* bezeichnet der Mathematiker gerne als »2-Tupel«, eine Dreiergruppe als »3-Tupel« usw. Für den allgemeinen Fall hat sich der Begriff »n-Tupel« etabliert.)

---

### Vektorraum *über* einem Körper

Vektoren sind geordnete n-Tupel bestehend aus Elementen einer bestimmten Menge. Wenn mit dieser Menge auch zwei innere Verknüpfungen (die man meist »Addition« und »Multiplikation« nennt) verbunden sind, die zusätzlich ganz bestimmte Eigenschaften haben, dann ist diese Menge ein Körper. Weil sich die Verknüpfungen samt ihren Eigenschaften auf die Vektoren vererben, bilden dann auch die Vektoren eine besondere algebraische Struktur, die man eben einen Vektorraum nennt.

Ein Vektorraum ist also die Menge aller Vektoren, deren Komponenten Elemente eines bestimmten Körpers sind.

Der Körper bildet sozusagen das Fundament, und **über** diesem Fundament kann man Vektorräume errichten.

---

### Zeichenkette *über* einem Alphabet

Das ist quasi 1:1 von den Vektoren und Körpern kopiert. Anstelle eines Körpers bildet hier ein Alphabet das Fundament. Auch ein Alphabet ist eine Menge, allerdings müssen innerhalb eines Alphabets keine Verknüpfungen zwischen den einzelnen Elementen (die »Zeichen« oder »Symbole« genannt werden) definiert sein. Damit kann man ebenfalls geordnete n-Tupel bilden, und diese n-Tupel sind dann Zeichenketten. (Der eingefleischte Mathematiker sagt aber lieber »Wörter« wenn er das meint, was ein Informatiker als »Zeichenkette« bezeichnen würde, wobei diese *Wörter* natürlich etwas völlig anderes sind als die *Wörter* des Otto Normalverbraucher.)

Also bildet hier ein Alphabet das Fundament, und **über** diesem kann man Zeichenketten errichten.

---

### Relation *auf* einer Menge

Und schon wieder haben wir geordnete n-Tupel vorliegen, wobei man im Normalfall von 2-Tupel, also Paaren ausgeht. (Will man diesen oft betrachteten Fall besonders bezeichnen, kann man auch von *zweistelligen* Relationen sprechen. Wenn nicht anderes erwähnt wird, ist mit »Relation« in der Regel eine zweistellige Relation gemeint)

Eine Relation ist nämlich eine Teilmenge aller möglicher geordneten Paare (oder manchmal auch größerer n-Tupel), wobei das erste und das zweite Element nicht zwingend aus derselben Menge kommen müssen. (Man kann z.B. auch die Menge aller österreichischen Bundesländer mit der Menge aller Landeshauptleute verknüpfen, und nur jene Paare in die Relation aufnehmen, bei denen die Person Landeshauptmann des verknüpften Bundeslandes ist.)

Wenn man aber eine Relation auf nur einer Menge hat, dann entstammen alle Elemente derselben Menge. (Beispiel: Man verknüpft die Menge aller Menschen mit sich selbst, und nimmt in die Relation nur jene Paare auf, bei denen die zweite Person ein Kind der ersten Person ist. Man erhält dadurch die Relation aller Eltern-Kind-Beziehungen)

Also ist auch hier eine Menge (die nun auch als solche bezeichnet wird, weil sie sonst keine besonderen Eigenschaften haben muss) ein Fundament, **auf** dem man eine Relation aufbauen kann.

---

### Funktion *auf* einer Menge

Jede Funktion ist eine Relation (nämlich eine linkstotale und rechtseindeutige zweistellige Relation). Daher gilt sinngemäß dasselbe, was bereits über die Relationen gesagt wurde.

---

### Allgemeiner Fall

Eine logische Erklärung für die Wahl zwischen *auf*, *über* und möglichen anderen Präpositionen gibt es nicht. Insbesondere kann daraus keine Regel abgeleitet werden, derzufolge man auch in anderen, ähnlichen Fällen eine sicher Wahltreffen könnte.

Dass man manchmal *auf* statt *über* verwendet, ist reine Konvention. Wer davon redet, dass man eine Relation *über* einer Menge errichtet, wird sicherlich auch verstanden werden, offenbart aber gleichzeitig, mit den üblichen Konventionen nicht vertraut zu sein.